# Is it good idea to authenticate every page of my website?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, authentication, jwt

I am currently using JSON Web Token to authenticate every page of my website except homepage. The idea is to generate token on login/registration with the user's MongoDB id and save that into cookies. Then whenever user tries to open any page, first token will be decoded and then id will be matched with the database records to verify that the correct user is trying to access page.

I haven't launched the website yet. My question is, is it a good practice to access database before every page loads for user or will it slow down my website once more users start coming on website?

Comment: You don't need to access the database every single time, you could store a session in memory and authenticate the cookie against that. The only upside to checking against the database every single time is that any changes to database records will be reflected immediately (typical caching issue). But really, how often will that make a difference?

Comment: @deceze thanks for your comment. The website contains multi-player board games and the idea behind authentication is to update balance of user whenever someone else played against him and he was not on the game screen. If user won and his balance isn't updated in front-end then he won't be able to know whether he won or lost without opening game screen again.

Comment: That is tangential to the question. *Authenticate* means that your web server establishes the identity of the user making the request. Just plain simply resolving "who is this guy?" The step after that would be *authorisation*, establishing whether the user is allowed to do whatever it is they're trying to do. After that comes updating of scores and whatnot. Both for authentication and authorisation you do not necessarily require database access, as long as the information required to complete the auth\* is stored elsewhere, e.g. in an in-memory session or cache.